# Zombicide: split problem

Tags: zombicide, zombicide-black-plague, zombies, zombicide-green-horde

In 2 corners are 3 survivors (S) each (3x noise), black field represents building which splits map. At the middle is a zombie wolf (W) which has 3 actions on activation. So how it should be played according to rules, because for me it’s unclear.

Start
[image]

After first action:
[image]

This is obvious, there exists two equal sources of noise, so the wolf should split in first action.

After second action:
[image]

Here it starts to be problematic, because according to rules distance to the source of noise doesn’t matter, so both wolves should split, because  there exists two equal sources of noise. And also to every group of survivors exists two equal roads. So these two wolves add two additional each, Correct ?!?!?!?

After third action:
[image]

And here is the final example of absurd these rules, two middle wolves just split due to 2 equal targets. It is easy, 2 wolves in corners should split also so for every wolf is added an wolf. And the biggest problem is wolves in the middle row, because again according to rules distance to the source of noise doesn’t matter, so both wolves should split, because  there exists two equal sources of noise. And also to every group of survivors exists two equal roads.So these two wolves add two additional each again.

So after one activation from one wolf according to rules we got 12 which is completely absurd. What is wrong in this consideration and how should it be played correctly ?

Answer (score 2):

## You've ignored the first rule of movement.

Once the zombies can see a survivor, they move towards that survivor only. That is, once you have done the first split, the two wolves will each move towards the nearest group.

You still end up splitting the wolves that are closest to the centre, because they have multiple paths towards the survivors they see, *but only towards **those** survivors*.

The splits and movements are, for each side,

1. Split from middle to adjacent space (one wolf in centre becomes one wolf on each side)
2. Split from first space to the one above and "outside" of it (one wolf on each side becomes two wolves on each side)
3. The "outside" wolf moves one space upward, and the "inside" wolf splits to the spaces above and "outside" (two wolves on each side becomes three wolves on each side)

The result is a situation similar to your third diagram, except it doesn't have two triplets of wolves waiting at the bottom.

Comment: OK, my mistake the wolves in corners indeed ares eeing survivors, but if for example, but if both group of survivors are hidden behind hedges ? This result is correct, after one turn  signle wolf could split into 12 ?

Comment: Yes, if you make a situation sufficiently convoluted or are that unlucky (or have mismanaged your noise that badly... :) there are situations that escalate from nothing to nightmare in a flash.

Comment: The rules of "Zombicide Green Horde" say regarding line of sight:
"On the streets, Actors see in straight lines that run parallel to the edges of the board. Actors cannot see diagonally. Their Line of Sight covers as many Zones as the line can pass through before reaching a wall or the edge of the board."
I assume that line of sight definition for zombies is the same as for actors because I have not found another specific definition for them in that rulebook. That given, the zombies **cannot see** the actors in the corner and **would still split up into the center**.